# Trouble adding react-testing-library to a project - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

Having trouble adding react-testing-library to a project.

Project is currently using these versions

```
"react": "16.10.2",
"react-dom": "16.10.2"
"jest": "24.9.0"
```

and I'm adding these versions for react-testing-library

```
"@testing-library/dom": "^6.10.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.1",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2"
```

Running a basic test like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

test('react-testing-library hello world', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(
        <div>Hello</div>
    );
    expect(getByText('Hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Gets this error for 'render()'

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined
```

Any ideas? Tried updating react and react-dom to latest and still got the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in my **jest.setup.js** document. I was mocking react-dom with

`jest.mock('react-dom');`

Removing this makes the test run as expected

[image: Screen Shot 2019-11-07 at 3 15 48 PM]

I ended up upgrading to these versions:

- `react`: 16.11.0
- `react-dom`: 16.11.0
- `react-test-renderer`: ^16.11.0
- `jest`: 24.9.0
- `node`: 10.16.3
- `@testing-library/dom`: ^6.10.1
- `@testing-library/jest-dom`: ^4.2.3
- `@testing-library/react`: ^9.3.2
- `@testing-library/user-event`: ^7.1.2

Hopefully, this will help someone else if they are having a similar issue!

Comment: Was there any solution to keep the `react-dom` mock?

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena I didn't look any further into it, as I didn't need that mock anymore